# singleton instance and workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton, unicorn

My application uses unicorn as production server with 4 workers.
For some reason i'm using a singleton class in my app logic. 
I'll get a total of 4 different class instances (each per worker) or only for all 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are going to get 4 different class instances.

Why?
unicorn loads rails -> forks worker processes.
Till now you have the Singleton Class loaded. But you have not `instantiated` the class till now (unless you are doing it in an `initializer`). So an instance for that class is not yet created. Now when a request is sent to unicorn worker, and when you try to `instantiate` singleton class, a `instance` is created, stored and will be `returned` every time the instance is accessed in that `worker`.